# What is the difference between milk (simple) and milk drink?

Tags: milk

Here in Finland I have come across two types of milk. One is simple milk (maito/mjölk) and the other is milk-drink (maitojuoma/mjölkdryck). They also have variations like fat-free, light, whole (hel/täys) and lactose(-free).

Lactose-free whole milk*drink* and whole milk, and light milkdrink and light milk have different tastes.

The difference between their ingredients is *milk-based mineral preparations*, *mineral product* or *mineral preparations*

Swedish:

> mjölkbaserat mineralpreparat (Milbona)
>
> mineralpreparat (Valio)

Finnish:

> maitopohjainen kivennäisvalmiste (Milbona)
>
> maitovalmiste (Valio)

They have different nutrition values but the same mineral value (only compared Milbona whole milk).

And both are placed in refrigerated compartments.

(I found milkdrink's taste slightly better.)

**Question:**

What is the differences between (simple) milk and milk-drink?

Comment: Have you read the ingredients?

Comment: Are both sold refrigerated? UHT milk has the same nutrition as pasteurised but here in the UK is often regarded as having an inferior flavour. That would be more of an issue when drinking it neat.

Comment: @Catija and @ ChrisH: question updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the milk is modified by removing the lactose, it is no longer considered *milk*, and must be sold under a different name, such as milk*drink*. The fat content can be modified while still considering it *milk* however.

The swedish FAQ of Valio (the biggest dairy producer in Finland) is very clear on this.

http://www.valio.se/halsa/laktosintolerans/fragor-och-svar

I couldn't however find the same quote in the Finnish FAQ (Via google translate).

http://www.valio.fi/usein-kysytyt-kysymykset/

While the legislation could in theory be different between the two countries, I believe this is probably regulated on EU level.

Comment: Good find. You might also want to add reference and excerpt of Helsingin Kaupunginkirjasto's (Helsinki City Library) answer to this question for completeness. http://www.kysy.fi/kysymys/mita-on-maitopohjainen-kivennaisvalmiste

Answer (score -3):

Wheresas on the other hand milk drink means, it's one kind of mixture which is making by some ingredients like fruits and others. Here I would like to mention that main aim behind making milk drink is provide vitamins and proteins in form of milk so its not too different from milk but its testing quality and other proportions are different from milk.

Comment: I've removed the portion of your answer which was a copied description of milk (please make it clear what parts of your answers are quotes, and cite sources).